# (foreach & isAssignableFrom) versus (OfType & foreach)

Tags: c#

My question is simple, which of these 2 code snippets is better?(quicker)

```
Foo[] foos = foosAndBars.OfType<Foo>().ToArray();
foreach(Foo foo in foos)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Or.....

```
foreach(FooBarParent foo in foosAndBars)
{
    if(typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(foo.GetType()))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Similar Questions: [How does OfType() Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833714/how-does-oftypet-work) and the question that is "almost" identical to this one: [LINQ + Foreach vs Foreach + If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072126/linq-foreach-vs-foreach-if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in terms of performance, in the first snippet you are iterating over ONLY Foos where as in the second instance you're iterating over everything and checking during the iteration if it is a Foo.

Second, in terms of readability, I would be a bit surprised if I found the second option, whereas the first is quite normal.

Finally, as Peter Duniho noted in the comments, you can save yourself the overhead of creating a new array altogether thanks to deferred execution.

```
foreach(Foo foo in foosAndBars.OfType<Foo>())
{  }
```

Comment: Note also that it would be more efficient and idiomatic to simply use `foreach (Foo foo in foosAndBars.OfType<Foo>())`, rather than copying the values to an array first.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach seem quicker since you just loop one time. And the first approach, because `ToArray` is called, so it will loop twice.

But, please note that, `OfType` is deferred execution and returns `IEnumerable` so you don't need to call `ToArray`, its performance will be better, I found the below code is more clean and readable:

```
var foos = foosAndBars.OfType<Foo>();
foreach(Foo foo in foos)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course, the first one is better. But still I would suggest you to use `as` or `is` validation to do something.

> First Approach

```
        object[] foosAndBars = new object[10];            
        foreach (var foo in foosAndBars)
        {
            if (foo is Foo)
            {
                // Do Something
            }
        }
```

> Second Approach

```
        foreach (var foo in foosAndBars)
        {
            Foo objFoo = foo as Foo;
            if (objFoo != null)
            {
                // Do Something
            }
        }
```

Comment: The isAssignableFrom is used because often I'm checking if foo implements an interface or inherits from another class. However regarding the as, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator it seems casting is preferred to the as statement.