# I can't change controls properties in my property setter?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, login and main, the main form is initially disabled (the `groupBox` is disabled) this is code that runs when the user tries to login:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (await VerifyUserNamePassword(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                Frm_Main main = new Frm_Main();
                main.Auth = true;
                Close();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password.");
        }
```

and this is the `Auth` property in the main form:

```
 public bool Auth
    {
        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                groupBox1.Enabled = true;
                logOffToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                loginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                listBoxUsers.DataSource = ctx.Users.ToList();
                listBoxUsers.DisplayMember = "UserName";
                listBoxUsers.ValueMember = "Id";
            }
        }
    }
```

I run the debugger, it passes through all theses lines, it supposed to change the properties, but it doesn't. after the login form closed the main form still as it was, disabled?
What am I missing?

Comment: Same problem an hour ago.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889810/listview-not-updating-when-method-is-called-from-another-instance/40890039#40890039

Comment: As said to the other guy. Your code creates a NEW instance of the main form. You call the property of that instance and work with the elements of that instance not the one already on display

Comment: So, should I make it `static`?

Comment: No you should find the reference to the main form on video. There are many ways to do it. Use the Application.OpenForms collection, pass the reference to main at the login form, raise an event and let the main form subscribe to the event,

Comment: What video please? I can't understand this, video tutorial?

Comment: I mean display, the reference to the main form already shown on your display.

Comment: Sorry I can't comment there, but how you are using the `OpenForms` like a method? shouldn't it be `OpenForms["Form1"]`

Comment: My error there. Just Appliction.OpenForms.OfType<.....>

Answer (score 1):

I think it is poor design to set in your login form the main.Auth.

The way i think is more appropriate is as follows:

1. In the loginForm have private boolean isLoginValid. Create a property for IsLoginValid. In the if statement you set the property IsLoginValid to true. Remove line to `Frm_Main main = new Frm_Main();`
2. In the main form you probably did something along the lines of login.ShowDialog() so after you process the login form, you assign within your main form `main.Auth = Login.IsLoginValid`

The reason this is preferred is that it separates your login and main forms logic. Please read about encapsulation and loosely-coupled applications

Comment: Thanks, this is even better